# Why won't null GameObjects be removed from List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

for some reason my code at the bottom of function TargetEnemy() doesn't work. I try to remove the null GameObjects from the List, but they remain in the list.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TurretController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform turretBulletSpawn;
    public GameObject turretBullet;

    public List <GameObject> storedEnemies = new List <GameObject>();

    void Start () 
    {

    }

    void Update ()
    {
        TargetEnemy();
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider enemyTriggered)
    {
        if (enemyTriggered.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            storedEnemies.Add(enemyTriggered.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit (Collider enemyTriggered)
    {
        storedEnemies.Remove(enemyTriggered.gameObject);
    }

    void TargetEnemy()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < storedEnemies.Count; i++)
        {
            Quaternion rotate = Quaternion.LookRotation(storedEnemies[i].transform.position - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotate, Time.deltaTime * 2);
            Instantiate (turretBullet, turretBulletSpawn.position, turretBulletSpawn.rotation);

            if (storedEnemies[i].gameObject == null)
            {
                storedEnemies.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't mark questions with things like "urgent"...

Comment: It isn't urgent, and that's not JavaScript.

Comment: ok, can you help me though

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unbearable

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge bug and you should try to remember this FOR EVER!
Let's assume targetEnemy has 3 records and the second one is null. 
Let us also assume your code would remove the null-records correctly.

The first two records would be handled correctly. 
But before the third iteration your list only contains 2 records and you are trying to access the third. That will throw an IndexOutOfrange or IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

This would be correct:

```
List<int> toRemove = new List<int>();

for(int i = 0; i < storedEnemies.Count; i++) {
   /*some code*/

   if(storedEnemies[i].gameObject == null) {
      toRemove.Add(i); //Note: I do not change your targetEnemy List
   }
}

//Iterate again and remove all stored indexes
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < toRemove.Count; i++) {
   storedEnemies.Remove(i - counter);
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: void TargetEnemy()
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < storedEnemies.Count; i++)
  {
   Quaternion rotate = Quaternion.LookRotation(storedEnemies[i].transform.position - transform.position);
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotate, Time.deltaTime * 2);
   Instantiate (turretBullet, turretBulletSpawn.position, turretBulletSpawn.rotation);

   if (storedEnemies[i].gameObject == null)
   {
    toRemove.Add[i];
   }
  }

  int counter = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < toRemove.Count; i++)
  {
   storedEnemies.Remove[i - counter];
   counter++;
  }
 }

Comment: how do i post the new changes

Comment: i declared it in the beginning of the script

Comment: @EugeneD The 3 lines where you instanciate your bullet are not correct. Your slerp doesn't work because you haven't understood how slerping or lerping works. There might be other problems but that is the next one I noticed. The first sample on this website shows how it is supposed to be done: https://chicounity3d.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/how-to-lerp-like-a-pro/

Comment: it does work though but the changes i have made from you code doesn't work